# would this vardump function work?

Tags: php, arrays, var-dump

```
$myarray = array("search1", "search2");

if(var_dump($myarray) == array){
  //do something
}
```

I was just curious if this if statement would return true ever

Comment: no, it won't return true. Even if you quote the word "array" (currently it's a syntax error)

Comment: You know there is a very popular compiler called `PHP` where you can test this out :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`var_dump` doesn't return anything, [`is_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) is probably the function you're looking for.